# How to I define the following in set builder notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A, B be sets. Sharon defines A % B to be the set of all subsets of A that also contain at least one element in B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A\%B=\{ x\in P(A)\mid x\cap B\neq\emptyset\}$, where $P(A)$ is the set of subsets of $A$ (the so-called "power set").

Comment: Fine. For technical reasons it would probably be better to write $\{ x\in P(A)\mid x\cap B\neq\emptyset\}$. See the remarks on the badness of "unrestricted comprehension" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification .

Answer (score 0):

$\{C: C\subset A\land C\cap B\ne \emptyset\}$....OR

$\{C\subset A: C\cap B\ne \emptyset\}.$

I prefer the colon $\;:\;$ to the vertical line $\;|\;$ because the vertical line has several other uses in math.